# oracle sql plus cuts off xml tags

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to generate a report in an XML format. However, when I try to run the entire data, it cuts off on the XML tags. It works fine if I reduce the output, but I need to have the entire data. The whole data is close to 1 million records.

This is what I have

```
SET ECHO OFF
SET LINESIZE 32767
SET PAGESIZE 0;
SET LONG 99999;
SET VERIFY OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
```

My desired output

```
<root>
  <user1><first_name>Maria</first_name><last_name>Doe</last_name></user1>
  <user2><first_name>Jane</first_name><last_name>Smith</last_name></user2>
  <user3><first_name>David</first_name><last_name></last_name>Doe</user3>
  <user4><first_name>Dani</first_name><last_name></last_name>Smith</user4>
  <user5><first_name>Ann</first_name><last_name>Smith</last_name></user5>
  <user6><first_name>Meg</first_name><last_name></last_name>Doe</user6>
</root>
```

But the tags get cutoff when I run large data

```
<root>
  <user1><first_name>Maria</first_name><last_name>Doe</last_name></user1>
  <user2><first_name>Jane</first_name><last_name>Smith</last_name></user2>
  <user3><first_name>David</first_name><last_name></last_name>Doe</user3>
  <user4><first_name>Dani</first_name><last_name></last_name>Smith</user4>
  <user5><first_name>Ann</first_name><last_name>Smith</last_name></us
er5>
  <user6><first_name>Meg</first_name><last_name></last_name>Doe</user6>
</root>
```

Notice **user5** its been pushed to the other line. Seems like white space.

Is there any workaround for this? I'm also trying to display it on one line.

Comment: How exactly are you doing that? All we know is that you have a problem, but people - who might assist - lack quite a lot of information. Which "client"? How does the result look like (what does "cuts off" mean)?

Comment: Umm, you are going to have to provide a lot more detail.  Please edit the question and post a [mcve]

Comment: Are you hitting the [SQL\*Plus LONG maximum size default of 80 characters?](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-61E0AB01-A2C4-4AAE-97C7-C5D8BE5DE1BF) If so, try running this command first: `set long 2000000000`

Comment: @JonHeller I tried that but didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @Littlefoot I have edited the question, please take a look.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I edited the question, please take a look

Comment: You need to show us how you are generating this output. You have the sqlplus tag on your question, so it's this calls to dbms_output?

Comment: @eaolson I'm using oracle xmlelement, xmlagg and xmlforest

Comment: Why don't you post code you use? It is difficult to debug something you can't see. I'm not saying that **I** can help, but those who could simply skip this question because it is incomplete so it is just a lot of guessing. It would be fine if you used e.g. Scott's EMP table.